# Record Button responses in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

Can any one here help me know how can I records button response in JMETER. when Ever I click a button, it calls a API. The API request and Response is recorded, but in HTTPS Request there is no such records captured which looks as a button I have clicked.

Say if I clicked Save, the save button action is not recorded, however ever the API that is called is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to "see" the button if 2 conditions are met:

1. The response of the API will contain the relevant [HTML input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_button.asp)

   [image]
2. You will be using `Browser` mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

   [image]

So if the button generates a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) which returns only data, not the UI elements like buttons, images, tables, etc. - you will not be able to see the button itself in the response, but you will see the button in the "previous" response for the request which "opened" this page with the button.

So

1. Record the whole test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)
2. Run it with View Results Tree listener in "Browser" mode enabled
3. Inspect the response to the request which is previous (or one of the previous) to the clicking the button

Comment: Thanks for your response, How to enable this Browser mode. ?
My API response a JSON and that is not having  relevant HTML input. I also tried to look prevoius pages to look for buttons in text response, but I am not seeing it.
My application is using Javascript

Comment: Just select it from the dropdown

Comment: it is like to select and manually inject the post or Get request, Is there a way to select it and then record like how it was in JMETER 2. There it was in Test script Recorder itself..